# How I can embed Microsoft-Word in my web application?

Tags: javascript, cgi

I want to run ms-Word as a text editor in my web application. I have tried some text editors like CKEditor, but the requirement is to bring "ms-office word" within a web page... Please help me to get solution for this..

Comment: You might want to look here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/javascript-api-for-office

Comment: Thank you Keith,  I read this but it is very confusing .. there is no any guidelines to implement that JavaScript files.